# Why does AVRDUDE require part ID as an input parameter when it detects the device signature by itself?

Tags: avr, programmer, avrdude, isp, usbasp

When I type the following in terminal

```
avrdude -p m32 -c usbasp
```

I get the following as output

```
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9502 (probably m32)

avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FF, H:99, L:E1)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

If you have noticed in the output, AVRDUDE reads the device signature and considers the part ID to be probably `mXX`. If this way it can detect the part ID by itself why does it require me to input the part ID under parameter `p` ?

Comment: Maybe it's important to know if the people programming know what part they're programming

Comment: `probably` is not `100% certainly`

Answer (score 1):

Probably a combination of needing the correct command set to communicate with it (an `m32` might not have all the ISP commands of an `m328`, etc.), auto-detect might be faulty (it seems there are rare cases of SIGROW getting overwritten -- it's supposed to be read-only but in reality it's Flash like any other, and put there by the manufacturer through undocumented means), or it needs at least a starting point to read such (maybe a class like `mega` would be enough of a start, but might as well fully specify it), or it's entirely just information and confirms signature for your convenience.

The technically correct answer is to peruse the source code and see what it does with it:

https://github.com/avrdudes/avrdude/

But I haven't looked very in-depth at all and it's quite a dense codebase to follow around command line parameters.  But, would be a good introduction to the project, if you're interested in knowing more about it.